# closed ε-ball around x

Tags: general-topology

Let (X,d) be a metric space. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and let $x \in X$.

We view X as a topological space w.r.t. the topology induced by d and write
$$\overline{B}_{\varepsilon}(x) = \{x' \in X \mid d(x,x') \leq \varepsilon\}$$
for the closed $\varepsilon$-ball around x.

I need to show that: $\overline{B_{\varepsilon}(x)} \subset \overline{B}_{\varepsilon}(x)$

I know that $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \subset \overline{B}_{\varepsilon}(x)$

So if I show that $\overline{B}_{\varepsilon}(x) \subset X$ is closed, then I am ready I think,
since the closure of a set is the smallest closed subset of X that contains this set.

How do I show that $\overline{B}_{\varepsilon}(x) \subset X$ is closed?
I think I can show this to show that the complement is open. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider $y\notin \bar{B}_{\epsilon}(x).$ Thus $d(y,x)>\epsilon.$ Say $d(y,x)=\epsilon+r$ for some $r>0.$ Show that $B_r(y)\cap \bar{B}_{\epsilon}(x)=\emptyset.$